# How do you live or survive in an area with hyper-inflation?

Tags: inflation, iran

I live in a place where the cost of products and services are rising rapidly and exponentially while people's earnings are almost the same with only minimal changes. For example, you need to work for 6 months to buy a cellphone! or 50 months to buy the cheapest (used) car!
Is it possible to survive in this situation?

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: @Flux - Iran IR.

Comment: Many countries in the 20th and 21st century (from the Weimar Republic to many Central and South American and African countries) have suffered hyperinflation.  Studying (and then asking about) what people did then is what I would suggest.

Comment: Bottom line, though: "spend now", before what money you *do* have becomes less worthy.

Comment: Iran has inflation of about [40% per year](https://www.npr.org/2021/06/28/1011043660/facing-40-inflation-iranians-wonder-if-and-when-their-economic-rebound-will-happ). Hyperinflation is [defined](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hyperinflation.asp) as more than 50% per *month*; that is a distinct problem that produces strange dynamics but is not present in this case. I think the biggest issue identified by the question is not inflation (change over time) but just absolute high prices (low purchasing power). The obvious implication is that most of the population cannot afford any luxuries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just like to add to sevensevens answer that this is one of the common cases where communities such as yours benefit from access crypto currencies directly. Very generally speaking crypto exchanges do not generate taxable events, are usually trivially acquired and offer you an easy way to store and convert your money into another currency.

The Eurozone had a large uptick in the adoption of crypto on the countries that most felt the aftermath of the Greek crisis. Venezuelan citizens regularly use it exactly as in your case, as an attempt to mitigate hyperinflation.

If you do decide to go down this route you can also look into stablecoins, just be aware that even hyper popular coins like Tether (USDT) have had some controversy regarding to how closely they actually track their parent currency. Make sure not keep keep them in whatever exchange you end up using, as it might be exposed to fraud, but in the same token make sure not to tell anyone that you do have crypto and keep your offline wallet hidden.

Also be aware that the main crypto currencies, even Bitcoin and Ethereum have high volatilities, perhaps it is still better than your countries currency. You should do some math to determine whether it is a worthwhile risk.

Comment: How did that work out for tulips?

Comment: What's the specific benefit of crypto over regular foreign currencies here? I see only disadvantages.

Answer (score 5):

Hyperinflation, unlike 'regular' inflation, is inflation that is so severe that currency, and prices denominated in that currency, are pretty much irrelevant.

There is no financial solution to this, because ultimately it is not an individual financial problem.

In a hyper-inflation scenario there is simply not enough stuff being produced to meet people's basic needs. Gold, silver, and foreign currencies will not help you, because you cannot eat them or live in them. When people are starving, nobody wants your gold. In that case what you need is your own source of food and shelter, and the ability to physically defend them.

All that said, as another poster mentioned, Iran may have high inflation, but probably not hyper-inflation. When there is food (to say nothing of cars and cell phones) on the shelf (however expensive) that is not hyper-inflation.

You can try gold or foreign currencies, but good luck with that. In many other countries with high inflation, this is exactly what citizens try to do: Hold physical Dollars and gold, and avoid local currency if at all possible. It's usually the first thing governments crack down on during normal-very-high inflation scenarios.

Comment: The last sentence is possibly because people who are doing such things are making the hyperinflation worse in a feedback loop.

Answer (score 4):

**Move your money into foreign currencies and precious metals**

The best way to protect your money against inflation is to convert it to foreign currencies such as the dollar and precious metals.

Once the country realizes it's citizens aren't using it's money it will likely outlaw holding large amounts of foreign currencies.  There is only so much precious metals available in your country so start buying NOW!

Hyperinflation is usually the beginning of the end for a government.  It essentially means that even it's own citizens won't take it's money, so they can't pay anyone.  Have an escape plan if possible.

**EDIT - Think hard about BTC**

You mentioned BTC.  BTC and crypto in general goes through some pretty wild swings in value.  BTC is very much a speculative investment.

Will most merchants in your country accept BTC?  If not, I wouldn't store money that way.  It'll just add a conversion step that'll cost you money.

Stick with gold and foreign currencies.  With inflation at 40% a year, you are not the only person finding a better store of value for your cash.  Likely merchants already accept both dollars and gold (and other precious metals) since they don't want to lose 40% a year either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your suggestion about investing in foreign currencies is good but what if those currencies lose value in my country too?

Comment: @Nariman Asgharian - That's why I recommended something like the U.S. dollar.  World events make it fluctuate, but to nowhere near hyperinflation levels.  Any store of value, including gold, will fluctuate in value over time.  The goal is to not lose 40% a year.

Comment: - In fact, you mean I can slow the process of losing value over time by investing in USD. I think investing in BTC (only BTC not other cryptos) could also be helpful in the long run.

Comment: BTC is likely a *horrible* way to store value long-term, at least if you enter now. Its price history since 2017 has been a series of increasingly extreme, unpredictable swings in price (both up and down). If you bought before 2020, you're in a good position *for now*. If you bought *during* 2020, you're probably ok, but if you bought anytime in 2021, you're as likely to have lost a lot of money as you to have gained any, and at no point as the price been *stable* for any extended period of time.

Comment: @Chepner - I agree with you about volatility of crypto but I didn't mean to invest all I have in cryptocurrency. My plan is (better to say was) to invest mainly in USD and metals for the long term and use a part of my money not to invest but to trade with crypto and earn money. I have traded with BTC since 2019 and have been successful to earn profit from it.

Comment: I don't hold crypto, I just buy and sell it. Even if BTC falls in value for a while, I don't sell it to lose money. I'll just wait for it to rise again and recover my losses. This way I have never lost anything on crypto. Since BTC has a high market capitalization, it almost never fails, it just fluctuates up and down.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian Then you are speculating in Bitcoin, not using it to preserve value.

Comment: @chepner - In bitcoin yes but in USD and metals no. My problem is not just keeping value, it is lack of earning. Without any source of earning, I will not survive. Here, working is not worth it because your earning will not be enough to meet your needs.

Comment: You have two independent issues: one is not being able to earn enough money to buy things *now* (for which long-term investments is not the solution), the other being able to preserve the value of what you have now (for which speculation is a risky, though technically feasible, solution).